# Custom JpaRepository filter or query

Tags: java, spring

I am getting all `Posts` per page with a limit of 10 with use of `JpaRepository` `findAll()` function. However, I would like to make a custom function in the `Interfce` to take only those records which have `PostType` equals to 2.

My interface class:

```
public interface PostRepository extends JpaRepository <Post, Integer> {

}
```

I use it like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/posts", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    Page<Post> getAllPosts(@RequestParam int page) {
        //int page=1;
         PageRequest request =
                    new PageRequest(page - 1, PAGE_SIZE, Sort.Direction.DESC, "CreationDate");
                return postRepository.findAll(request);
    /*  List<Post> list = (List<Post>) postRepository.findAll();
        return new ResponseEntity<List<Post>>(list, HttpStatus.OK);*/
    }
```

With the above code, I am getting all posts. I need to use my custom `findOnlyQuestions()` to get all questions per page.

*(Only some of the posts are questions)*

I think I saw somewhere I could edit query with a `@Query` annotation and achieve it like that. What do you think?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could actually use a method with special name:

```
Page<Post> findByPostTypeEqual(Pageable pageable, int postType);
```

So when you call a method, just pass 2.

Not sure whether it will work (it works when you want to limit number of fetched records), but try like this too:

```
Page<Post> findByPostTypeEqual2(Pageable pageable);
```

With @Query annotation you would have:

```
@Query("select p from Post p where p.postType = 2")
Page<Post> findByPostType(Pageable pageable);
```

Comment: I think you are right, I will let you know by accepting the answer soon :). Thank you.